# Activeadmin - how to pass the current filtered result to a custom action in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Using rails 6.0.2.1 & ActiveAdmin 2.6.1

I would like to pass the current filtered result to a custom collection action. It seems that both `collection` and `purchases` gives me the paginated set, but I want to pass the entire result set, returned by the current filter settings, back to the custom controller action.

```
  action_item :start_export, only: :index do
    link_to 'Export', export_admin_purchases_path(collection: purchases)
  end
  
  collection_action :export, method: :get do
    @purchases = params[:collection]
    # Do some special CSV exporting work here...
    redirect_to admin_purchases_path, notice: "CSV imported successfully!"
  end
```

As an alternative, I've tried this...

```
  action_item :start_export, only: :index do
    link_to 'Export', export_admin_purchases_path(collection: purchases.map {|purchase| purchase.id})
  end
```

...but I'm only able to capture the id's from purchases on the current page. I need the id's of all purchases in the current filtered result.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You can get current filter from params['q'] and then pass it to export_admin_purchases_path and use ransack to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ActiveAdmin Scoped Collection Actions](https://github.com/activeadmin-plugins/active_admin_scoped_collection_actions) either to use directly or for code to reuse.